# Q: What is the power of this signal

Tags: power, signal, energy

Determinate the power of the discrete signal:

$$x[n] = u[n] + (-1)^n + (\frac{-1}3) ^n * u[n]$$

where:  $$u[n] =
\begin{cases}
\ 1,  & n \ge 0 \\[2ex]
0, & n \lt 0
\end{cases}$$

The answer I got is 1 (Correction: the answer i got is 1.5), but i'm not sure if it's the right answer.

What I did:

knowing that $$Px = \lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{2N+1}*\sum_{n=-N}^N x[n]^2$$

then you put all inside the limit:

$$Px = \lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{2N+1}* [(\sum_{n=0}^N 1)+(\sum_{n=-N}^N((-1)^2)^n) + (\sum_{n=0}^N ((\frac{-1}3)^2) ^n)] $$

now we have: $$(\sum_{n=0}^\infty ((\frac{-1}3)^2) ^n) = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{9}}  = 0.9$$

$$(\sum_{n=0}^N 1) = N+1$$

$$(\sum_{n=-N}^N((-1)^2)^n) = 2N+1$$

so: $$Px = \lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{2N+1}* [(N+1)+(2N+1) + (0.9)] $$

$$Px = \lim_{N\to \infty} [(\frac{N+1}{2N+1} )+(\frac{2N+1}{2N+1}) + (\frac{0.9}{2N+1})] $$

Applying the limit:
$$Px = [(\frac{1}{2} )+(1) +0] $$

Result: Px = 1.5

Comment: Then show us how, and where is your doubt

Comment: Please show the methods that you used to calculate the power, then ask where you went wrong. We don't do homework for people here, so your going to have to show some work. Be specific and show your research.  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @laptop2d ok, sorry..

Comment: Although some of your intermediate steps are a bit questionable, it looks like you ended up with the right answer. BTW, I edited your question to format the Mathjax more clearly and switch the control variable for the limits from T to N.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks ! So is this the correct answer ?